# Adding placeholder attribute to a span with textarea role

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

```
  <span
    role="textbox"
    placeholder={"Amazing Title"}
    contentEditable
    className={styles.StrapLineInput}
  ></span>
```

I'm creating a react app. I'm using span with role instead of actual textarea inorder to make the input area height automatically vary with the number of lines entered. I would like to give it a placeholder too. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

```js
document.querySelector("span").focus()
```

```css
span[placeholder]:empty:before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
    color: #555; 
}
span{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
  <span
    role="textbox"
    placeholder="Amazing Title"
    contentEditable="true"
    className="input"
  ></span>
```

Comment: Your answer helps! Thanks a lot! Stay safe!

Answer (score 2):

Here,

I have made a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/opfhts62/) with the CSS attribute

```
span.class[contenteditable] {
  display: inline-block;
}

span.class[contenteditable]:empty::before {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  display: inline-block;
}

span.class[contenteditable]:empty:focus::before {
  content: attr(data-focused-advice);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I added some CSS style as you mentioned *input area height automatically vary with the number of lines entered* with blinking cursor visible at beginning as `input`.

You can feel free to add your value for padding, width, border, etc..

```css
span{
    outline: none;
    min-height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 8px 8px 4px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #708090;
    display:inline-block;
    width:330px;
}

span:empty:before {
    content: attr(placeholder);
    color: #aaa; 
}
```

```html
<span role="textbox" placeholder='Amazing Title' contentEditable=true ></span>
```